# MVC ToString instead of Template

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to get a template for a list of objects in MVC 5 with EF.

Instead of getting the template i supplied, i get the toString of "Class" (one of the proerties in the model)

i have looked all over the place and found nothing to help me.

any help will be greatly appreciated!

what i get is:

> Levels This is the goddamn ToString of Class

I have the following:

ClassSpellLevelPair.cshtml (tried to put it in Shared, EditorTemplates and the folder with Create.cshtml):

```
@model Analyzer.Models.ClassSpellLevelPair
<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Class.Name)
    @Html.ValueFor(model => model.SpellLevel)
</div>
```

in the create.cshtml:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Levels, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
    <div class="col-md-9">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Levels, "ClassSpellLevelPair")
    </div>
 <div>
```

the models are:

```
public class Spell : Entity
{
    ...
    [Display(Name = "Levels")]
    public virtual ICollection<ClassSpellLevelPair> Levels { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class ClassSpellLevelPair : Entity
{
    public ClassSpellLevelPair()
    {

    }

    public ClassSpellLevelPair(Class c, int? l = null)
    {
        Class = c;
        SpellLevel = l;
    }

    public Class Class { get; set; }

    public int? SpellLevel { get; set; }
}

public class Entity
{
    public Entity()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

edit: added folder data for ClassSpellLevelPair.cshtml

Comment: Which folder is `ClassSpellLevelPair.cshtml` located in?

Answer (score 1):

Found out that the "EditorTemplates" folder is actually "Shared\EditorTemplates"

so obvious that it took an overall of 6 hours google-ing.